# Returning Saved Entity Reference

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am looking for feedback on drawbacks to the following:

```
Person person = personRepository.save(personForm);
```

I want to know if this could potentially return an `ID` belonging to another record if both records were saved at the same time. If that is a possibility, should this be wrapped in a transaction of with a `begin/commit`?

I Googled this quite a bit and only ran across examples requiring the use of `EntityManager` and flushing and saving etc. I could not find an example similar to the one I supplied.

Look forward to the answers and thank you in advance.

Comment: No, it won't. But all the usages of JPA should be done in a transactional context. A Spring should start and commit the transaction for you. Read the documentation about Spring transaction management.

Comment: Is annotating the class/methods with @Transactional(...) enough to say that we are telling Spring to handle transactions or do I have to literally wrap the call with something before and after?

Comment: Provided you have correctly configured a transaction manager and enabled annotatiion-based transaction handling as exlained in the docuentation, all you need is to annotate the method or class.